# Utilizar selectores para DOM dentro de una variable con HTML

Tags: javascript, nodejs, dom, ecmascript-6, selectores-css

Tengo en Javascript una variable que incluye todo un fichero html, ¿mi pregunta es, no puedo utilizar los métodos del DOM para tratar esta variable y sacar solo los datos que me interesen? He probado a poner:

```
variable.querySelector('td').innerTEXT
```

No puedo usar Jquery.

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: ¿Qué significa *todo un fichero html*? ¿una variable con texto?

Comment: Sí, una variable cuyo texto al completo es html. @PabloLozano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la variable es puro texto, tienes un `String`, no un `HTMLDocument`. Para poder hacer *queries* primero debes transformarlo, lo que puedes hacer con un `DOMParser`. Una vez *parseado*, puedes buscar lo que quieras:

```js
const texto = `<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
//parseamos el string
let doc = parser.parseFromString(texto, 'text/html');

//comprobamos que tiene un H1 y mostramos su texto
console.log(doc.querySelector('h1').innerText)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, de verdad. Los `` son obligatorios?

Comment: Usar \` permite escribir un string de varias líneas: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings